# How to put an picture to an object in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, 2d-games

Well I try to make an object an image, an object that goes into an ArrayList. But I don't know how to do it. I tried several methods but none of them I tried did not work. What do you think should be added? And my object is called Apple.Thanks in advance

```
    public class Gamepanel extends JPanel {

     public void tick()
    {
         if(apples.size()==0)
        {
            //System.out.println(apples.size());
            int xC=r.nextInt(79);

            int yC=r.nextInt(79);

            apple=new Apple(xC,yC,10);
            apples.add(apple);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<apples.size();i++)
        {
            if(xC==apples.get(i).getxC()&&yC==apples.get(i).getyC())
            {   
                size++;
                score++;
                apples.remove(i);
                i++;

            }
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {   

        //here I draw the snake and his food    
        if(State==STATE.GAME)
        {
            g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        //here i make my map of the game 

        for(int i=0;i<apples.size();++i)
        {
            apples.get(i).draw(g);
        }


}
```

public class Apple {

```
private int xC,yC,width,height;

BufferedImage ap=null;

public Apple(int xC,int yC,int titleSize) {

    this.xC=xC;
    this.yC=yC;
    width=titleSize;
    height=titleSize;   
}
//here i want to draw a picture for each my objects from ArrayList
public void draw(Graphics g) 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're meaning by make an object an image... I don't see any code with the definition for apple...

Have you tried using Textures? You can easily create a Texture[] array containing different textures for use.

```
Texture[] apples = new Texture[2];

apples[0] = new Texture("apple1.png");
apples[1] = new Texture("apple2.png");
```

ArrayLists can also be used, but my experience with 2d games is in using libGDx (im guessing your package is graphics2D? with GDx you can...

```
SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();

ArrayList<Texture> apples = new ArrayList<Texture>();

//add your textures, then draw using a SpriteBatch

batch.begin();
batch.draw([texture],xpos,ypos); batch.draw(apples.get(i), 150, 500);
batch.end();
```

Comment: this is my code for apple  `public class Apple {
 private int xC,yC,width,height;

 BufferedImage mar=null;

 public Apple(int xC,int yC,int titleSize) {
  
  this.xC=xC;
  this.yC=yC;
  width=titleSize;
  height=titleSize; 
 }
 
 

 public void draw(Graphics g) 
 {
  }
}
`

Comment: you'd be better off editing your original post with that info and also how you populate your apples ArrayList